# Spring MVC, Hibernate Entity Manager Configuration for Module Access

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC with Maven and I have a structure of modules a below.

The Web Project is MVC Module I moved the models which I was using in Web Module to the Model Module. It compiles and runs just ok.

But when i try to use the entity manager I get an **Unknown Entity Error**.

Is there a configuration which I am missing to add for my entity manager configuration to access the model classes in the Model Module?

I added the dependencies for the Model Module in the Web Module and I can access the classes in the Model module. But the entity manager looks like just cant access the model module.

```
 main
 |
 --Web
 |
 --Model
```

**jpaContext.xml:**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject"/>


<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Web?autoReconnect=true" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="123456" />
</bean>
```

**POM.XML FOR MODEL MODULE**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
   <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>main</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Model</artifactId>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

 </dependencies>
```

**POM.XML FOR WEB MODULE**

```
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>Web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>Model</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: You'll need to post more info here, such as your configuration.

Comment: You can use this very good bootstrap https://github.com/paukiatwee/webapp-bootstrap if you have problems. You can see how the configuration must be.

Comment: Here you go All the configurations are included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the that the Entity Manager config file in my case jpaContext.xml was in my WEbModule/Resources Folder and The Web Module had a dependency on Model Module for using the Entity Classes which were defined in the Model Module.

The Entities In the Model Module which has the @Entity Annotation by default searches for the entity manager and because the Entity manager is defined in the Web Module I cannot reach it thats why I was getting the entity not found error. And in my case Because my Web Module already refers to Model Module, due to circular dependency I cant refer Model Module to Web Project.

```
The soultion was to move my jpaContext.xml to Model Module and Works Just Fine
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="packagesToScan">com.myproject.model</property>

    ... other properties ...

</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i figured out the problem i will post t as answer.